# Best way to Insert multiple new rows for custom module inside foreach loop

Tags: magento-1.9, module

To insert multiple records inside foreach loop we have two options:

example:

```
foreach($result as $data):

$_model=>Mage::getModel('');
 $_model->setField1()
 $_model->setField2()
 $_model->setField3()
 $_model->setField4()
 $_model->save()
endif;
```

or

`direct SQL query in foreach loop.`

Unfortunately both are **time consuming** process if the loop executes for 10-30 times.

Anyone have any idea as how to make this process faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if we want to go with magento only then below code works great, I used  `$_model->unsetData();` i don't need to load model in foreach loop.

```
$_model=>Mage::getModel('');

foreach($result as $data):
 $_model->setField1()
 $_model->setField2()
 $_model->setField3()
 $_model->setField4()
 $_model->save()
 $_model->unsetData();
endif;
```

Comment: ->unsetData() is what I missed!

Answer (score 12):

If they are new rows, you can use the insertMultiple method from the Magento DB Connection class:

```
$results = array(
    array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2'),
    array('field1' => 'value3', 'field2' => 'value4'),
    array('field1' => 'value5', 'field2' => 'value6')
);
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$connection->insertMultiple('your_db_table', $data);
```

This will be executed in a single query.